# Nav bar items are justified, but clicking the middle one causes it to shift left

Tags: html, css

I'm making the outline for my website and I'm having a problem with my nav bar at the top. The nav bar works fine on my index.html and contact.html, but when I click the middle link **about.html**, the item shifts to the left on the next page.

I think it has something to do with (display: flex) and (justify-content: space-between), but I don't really know. **I've provided two JSFiddles at the bottom to show the differences.**

**HTML**

```
    <html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Cameron Behbahany</title>
    <meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="Portfolio">
    <meta name="AUTHOR" content="Cameron">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <p class="headerleft">
            <a class="link" href="index.html">PROJECTS</span>
            <span id="clicked">ABOUT</span>
            <a class="link" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        </p>

        <p class="headerright">
            <a class="logolink" href="index.html">BEHBA</a>
        </p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;}

.headerleft {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 275px;
    font-family: "Nexa";
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: lightgrey;}

@font-face {
    font-family: "NexaBlack";
    src: url(fonts/'NexaBlack.otf');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;}

.headerright {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: "Nexa";
    font-size: 31px;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: grey;}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: lightgrey;}

.link:hover {
    border-bottom: 6px solid grey;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    color: grey;}

#clicked {
    color: grey;
    border-bottom: 6px solid grey;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: default;}
```

index.html
http://jsfiddle.net/9uu5aLv9/

**about.html (this is the one with the problem)**
http://jsfiddle.net/udoe9k3t/

Comment: You're closing an a tag with </span> in your second fiddle :) Replace with </a>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **about** menu item are in the span element right now. please move to anchor tag instead of span. `<span id="clicked">ABOUT</span>` to `<a id="clicked">ABOUT</a>`.
also there was a error in your code the first menu item opening in a `<a>` tag and ending with `<span>` that and should be end with the `<a>` tag.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Cameron Behbahany</title>
    <meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="Portfolio">
    <meta name="AUTHOR" content="Cameron">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <style>
    .header {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;}

.headerleft {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 275px;
    font-family: "Nexa";
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: lightgrey;}

@font-face {
    font-family: "NexaBlack";
    src: url(fonts/'NexaBlack.otf');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;}

.headerright {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: "Nexa";
    font-size: 31px;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: grey;}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: lightgrey;}

.link:hover {
    border-bottom: 6px solid grey;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    color: grey;}

#clicked {
    color: grey;
    border-bottom: 6px solid grey;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: default;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <p class="headerleft">
            <a class="link" href="index.html">PROJECTS</a>
            <a id="clicked" href="javascript:void(0)">ABOUT</a>
            <a class="link" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        </p>
        <p class="headerright">
            <a class="logolink" href="index.html">BEHBA</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am recommending the best practice are the list item for the navigation menu.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The above comment mentioned I closed an <a> tag with a </span>. Silly little mistakes. Thanks for your help.